# ArcGIS Pro won't export unique identifier of View table to table

Tags: arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase

I have a view on a SQL Server enterprise SDE, with fields LocationID, RecordCount, Min, Max, etc.  Just basic stats generated from another table.  When I import the view into a map project, I choose LocationID as the unique identifier and it's fine.  But when I attempt to export the view to a table or csv file, the LocationID is excluded from the export.

I ran into this issue in ArcMap and I can't find any references to the issue or complaints on the ESRI boards.

Anyone have any insight or solutions to this?